# How Copy selected Rows data from multiple sheets to Main sheet

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I want copy rows data from different sheets to single (MAIN) sheet.
Kindly Help

```
For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
        For r = 1 To Rows.Count
            If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                With Worksheets("Main")
                    LRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Range("C" & LRow & ":J" & LRow) = _
                    Worksheets("2nd-Party").Range("C" & r & ":J" & r).Value
                    Worksheets("2nd-Party").Range("C" & r & ":J" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next r
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is this your code? Are you getting any error?

Comment: single sheet (name as 2nd-Party) to Main Sheet work perfect. now i want work from multiple sheets to Main Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Macro will loop from sheet 2 to sheet 4. You can easily change that in: sheetNr = 2 To 4.

```
For sheetNr = 2 To 4
    For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
            For r = 1 To Rows.Count
                If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top Then
                    With Worksheets("Main")
                        LRow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        .Range("C" & LRow & ":J" & LRow) = _
                        Worksheets(sheetNr).Range("C" & r & ":J" & r).Value
                        Worksheets(sheetNr).Range("C" & r & ":J" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                    End With
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next r
        End If
    Next
Next sheetNr
```

If you prefer using names of the sheets you can define an array containing names of your sheets and then using for loop grab these names

SheetName = Array("1st-Party", "2nd-Party", "3rd-Party")

```
For i = 0 to 2
...
Worksheets(SheetName(i)).Range("C" & r & ":J" & r).Value
...
next i
```